# Phalcon UnitTesting

Tags: php, unit-testing, phalcon

I am running the example from the documentation: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/unit-testing.html#sample-unit-test

I want to create an abstract unit test from Phalcon\Test\UnitTestCase as in the documentation. However when I run my test I become:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Phalcon\Test\UnitTestCase' not found
```

I have followed the exact documentation steps. Did anyone have the same problem and solved it?

Comment: Do you have autoloading configured in your project?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This class is part of the incubator: https://github.com/phalcon/incubator

```
$loader = new Phalcon\Loader();

$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Phalcon' => '/path/to/incubator/Library/Phalcon/'
));

$loader->register();
```

Comment: I am getting the same. I used composer to do the installation. But still I get it. Isn't composer install them in the correct locations? Bit confused...

Answer (score 3):

I figure it out.

Basically we have to do 2 things.

1. is whats in the @twistedxtra's answer. (setting up the path to where the incubator is)
2. in the `testsTestUnitTest.php` we created, it has the following line

`class UnitTest extends \UnitTestCase {`

we have to change that line to

`class UnitTest extends \Phalcon\Test\UnitTestCase {`

What we did was set the proper namespace so that the code knows where the `UnitTestCase` class is.

Thats it. Cheers...!!!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you run phpunit command **in** tests folder. It's very important.

Don't run something like `phpunit tests/`

Comment: no idea why this was downvoted, as this is clearly one of the many problems and the suggestion is right! I had the very same problem, just because I was running it from different directory, and autoloader failed to match the paths correctly.